# Problem with compilation in VS Code. IncludePath error

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include

I have a big problem with compilation of my program in VS Code. I'm writing a simple program but when I try to compile it and run it shows 2 problems. (I'm trying to translate it as clear as I can).

1. There is a problem with element #include. Please upgrade element includePath.
2. Can't open source file "stdio.h"

I'm writing the program in C language. I have to say that I'm a fresh programmer so if you can help me, please write it as simple as it's possible.

I'm adding the program, but I think it's very simple and that's not the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("costam\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code you posted, but rather in the way you are using Visual Studio Code. Since I don't use it, I'm afraid I cannot help you, but somebody else may be able to. I'm sure there are also tutorials on the Internet which explain how to compile your first C program with Visual Studio Code. For example, you may want to try [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Visual+Studio+Code%22+how+to+compile+your+first+C+program).

Comment: I really can't overcome that problem. Google methods did not work for me.

Comment: If you can't find any other help, you may want to enter the exact error message into Google. That way, you will possibly find posts of other people who have the same problem. However, entering the exact error message in English will likely yield better search results than entering it in your native language. Therefore, you may want to use Visual Studio Code in English to obtain the exact error message in English. Entering your translated error message will likely not work as well, because the wording will be different from the original English error message.

Comment: Also, [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22Visual+Studio+Code%22+includepath) may help. With me, one of the first three search results is a StackOverflow question on setting `includePath`.

Comment: Just for clarification: In your question, you say there are two problems. However, it seems to actually be only one problem. The second error message is likely a consequence of the problem specified in the first error message. Therefore, I suggest you concentrate your efforts on fixing the first error message.